# How to create login page that uses websphere repositories?

Tags: java, websphere, jaas

I want to create a simple JSP/Servlet login page that authenticate using websphere ldap repository.
All examples I've found looks very complex, with hundreds of lines of code just to authenticate.

Is this really so complex?

Does anyone have a simple example or article that explains how to authenticate a user/pass against a ldap repository already configured as websphere federated repository?

I really appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to secure a Web application or the WebSphere Application Server environment itself?

Comment: Web application

Comment: Which version of WebSphere Application Server are you looking to implement this in? (trying to narrow down the possible list of links to what will be relevant to you)

Comment: I'm using WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quit simple in reality. You need following pieces:

1) Login page with form that points to j_security_check
See this page for details [Customizing web application login](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_pofolo.html)

Very simplified example is like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
<input type="text" name="j_username">
<input type="text" name="j_password" autocomplete="off"> 
<\form>
```

2) Security configured in `web.xml`

Something like this:

```
<login-config>
<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
<realm-name>Example Form-Based Authentication</realm-name>
<form-login-config>
<form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
<form-error-page>/login.jsp</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

plus security constraint:

```
<security-constraint>
        <display-name>allResources</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>allResources</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>users</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

3) Application security enabled on the application server and user registry configured.

That's it.

Comment: Worked perfectly! But now I have the following problem.
My project is deployed at /TrainingProject, where I have index.html and login.html... It goes directly to index.html without request for login and I would like to force it. Is this possible?

Comment: @RanieriMazili This is strange, because if you used above security-constraint with pattern `/*` , all application resources, including index.html should be protected, and login form should be automatically presented if you access index.html. So something must be missing - either application security not enabled, or users role mapped to 'everyone' instead 'all authenticated'

Comment: Ok, this feature isn't essential at the moment. I have another doubt.
To make it work with Single Sign On, do I have to do any modifications in the current code or it will deal with it automacally once I setup everything in WAS side?

Comment: you were right, Enable application security was disabled, after enable it authentication is madatory to open index.html and other pages. Thanks.
I'll create another post that points to this one asking about Single Sign On. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @RanieriMazili, yes application security is required. Glad to hear that it worked for you. ;-)

Comment: your answer has one error, it's not closing auth-method tag, you missed the character "/", please fix it so others can use without problems ;)